# why does it not zoom?

Tags: ios, objective-c

new to objective c!

Im trying to make my mapview zoom. I've copied some code from a assignment in my book, but it somehow doesn't zoom. Just shows the unzoomed mapview.

Any suggestions? See The viewController code below.

Also - a few words on the difference of importing a header file and the @class directive would be great!?

Thanks in advance

```
#import "TrackViewController.h"
#import "MainWindowViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>



@class MainWindowViewController;
@implementation TrackViewController

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
{    
    self=[super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

if(self)
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
}
    return self;
}

-(IBAction) back:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) findLocation;
{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void) foundLocation:(CLLocation *)loc
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [loc coordinate];
    MKCoordinateRegion region =  MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 100, 100);
    [worldView setRegion:region];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [worldView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    [worldView setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];    
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [locationManager setDelegate:nil];
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager
 didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
        fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

NSTimeInterval t = [[newLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow];
if(t<180){
    return;
}
    [self foundLocation:newLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Could not find location: %@", error);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I notice is to change your setRegion line to:

```
[worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];//instead of just setRegion
```

-The `setRegion:` documentation states:

`The area currently displayed by the map view`

-While the `setRegion:animated:` documentation states:

`Changes the currently visible region and optionally animates the change`

Otherwise, I recommend printing out your `CLLocationCoordinate2D` object and ensuring it is valid.

Comment: i did just use setRegion?
where should i try printing the CLLocationCoordinate2d object?

Comment: Its a different method. setRegion is not the same as setRegion:animated: